# How does following program work?

Tags: c++, constructor

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

 cout << int() << endl;

 return 0;

}
```

- output is 0
- Is int() an inbuilt function in iostream?

Answer (score 3):

It's called [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

> ...
>   4) otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

Answer (score 0):

> Is int() an inbuilt function in iostream?

No - `int()` has nothing to do with `iostream`.  It can be used outside any IO streaming operations, and generates a temporary value of type `int` with value `0`.  Similarly, you could generate a value of some other type to stream, such as `float(0.1)` or `double()`.  The parentheses trigger value initialisation if no value is explicitly provided, as explained further by Sam.